Sitecore GraphQL isn't returning any results if search by id or any other field
I am new to GraphQL and running the following query without any success. Just search by id which isn't returning any results. Any help is highly appreciated.  If I remove the fieldsEqual I see the results are being returned.  Thanks
{
   search(
    index: "events_master_index"
    language: "en"
      fieldsEqual: [{
        name:"id",
        value:"7790D054XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}]
  )
  {
    results {
      items {
        name
        id
        language
        item {
          url
          PageTitle: field(name: "PageTitle"){
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


In order to search the item by id on Graphql, use the _group keyword as below.
query {
  search(
    fieldsEqual:[{name:"_group", value:"3fe5dda607ac4915bb5f2a291964a4e0" }]
  ){
    results{
      items{
        name
        id
        language
        item {
          url
          PageTitle: field(name: "PageTitle"){
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

This will return the item with that id. Note: Id must be entered in Guid format.

Hope this helps!!!

@ImranHamid Did you entered the value in lower case without any hyphens like this 3fe5dda607ac4915bb5f2a291964a4e0.

yes the case matters even through it returns in capital. Turning it to lowercase works!. Thanks very much. Is there a documentation where we can see the list of fields/custom fields we can use?

@ImranHamid Glad it worked!!! All the fields that exist on Solr can be queried, just make sure you are entering those field as defined on Solr schema. Foreg. when search in Title field you can query like fieldsEqual:[{name:"title", value:"Keyword to search for" }]. Hope this helps!!!

Sitecore GraphQL Search Query - fieldsEqual parameter
In this query:

We utilize the fieldsEqual parameter to specify criteria for filtering search results based on the equality of field values.

2.Two conditions are set: one for the “subtitle” field with the value “praveen” and another for the “description” field with the value “sharma”.
3.The rootItem parameter defines the starting point of the search within the Sitecore content tree, limiting the search scope to the specified node.
{
  search(
    fieldsEqual:[
      {name:"subtitle", value:"praveen" }
      {name:"description", value:"sharma" }
    
    ] 
    
    rootItem:"/sitecore/content/Home/MyProject/Home"
        ) {
    results {
      items {
        item {
          id
          name
          path
          url
         FirstName: field(name  : "subtitle") {
           value
          }
         LastName: field(name  : "description") {
           value
          }
        }
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
}


Hope this helps!!!
For more graphql queries you can visit : A Guide to Useful Queries
https://medium.com/@praveensharma6019/unlocking-the-power-of-graphql-in-sitecore-a-guide-to-useful-queries-e252fd9c8042
